# Select em coluna do tipo varchar que contenham apenas uma palavra

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Como executar uma SQL SELECT que busque apenas resultados do tipo VARCHAR que contenham apenas uma palavra? Ou seja, **não quero resultados com mais de uma palavra**

Comment: Como fazer uma boa pergunta? Acesse o link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Supondo que quando o campo possui mais de uma palavra elas estão separadas por espaço então utilize NOT LIKE '% %'.

Comment: Geniiaaal a do espaço, não havia pensado nisso!

Comment: Com algumas funções é possível fazer está checagem:  CHARACTER_LENGTH(SuaColuna) as 'numcaracteres', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SuaColuna, ' ', 1), ' ', -1)  AS primeironome
 ,TRIM( SUBSTR(SuaColuna, LOCATE(' ', SuaColuna)) ) AS sobrenome,
  if(TRIM( SUBSTR(SuaColuna, LOCATE(' ', SuaColuna)) ) = '','CONTEM PRIMEIRO','POSSUI SEGUNDO NOME') AS VERIFICACAO